# Understanding the output from a factor analysis using the FAMD function

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I have some survey data where people were asked questions and given a yes or no option (1=yes, 0=no). I would like to be able to pick out some patterns in this data.

The questions are:

1. Do you enjoy XX work?
2. Do you do XX work alone?
3. Has your workload increased?
4. Do you have a backlog of work?

I would like to know whether people who work alone are more likely to have an increased workload, a backlog of work and not enjoy their job. To answer this, I think factor analysis is the way to go but I'm struggling to interpret the output.

Here is an example of my data:

```
enjoy <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
alone <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)
workload <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
backlog <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0)
data <- data.frame(enjoy, alone, workload, backlog)
data <- data %>% mutate_if(sapply(data, is.numeric), as.character) ## convert from numeric to categorical
```

I'm using the FAMD function in factomineR as this can use categorical data.

```
library(FactoMineR)
data_famd <- FAMD(data, graph = FALSE)
```

Then using factoextra, I can see which variables contribute to each axis

```
library(factoextra)
# Contribution to the first dimension
fviz_contrib(data_famd, "var", axes = 1) ## backlog & workload
# Contribution to the second dimension
fviz_contrib(data_famd, "var", axes = 2) ## enjoy and alone
```

Then I can make this plot:

```
fviz_mfa_ind(data_famd, 
         habillage = "alone", # color by groups 
         palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
         addEllipses = TRUE, ellipse.type = "confidence", 
         repel = TRUE) # Avoid text overlapping
```

[image]

This looks like that people who work alone vs not alone answer questions differently. But I don't understand what answers people who work alone (yellow) are giving vs people who don't work alone. They are clearly distinct so are doing something differently.

My main question is: What do the axes mean? I've done PCA's using continuous data before and using the loadings I can figure out what the axes mean, and therefore interpret these graphs. How do you do this for a factor analysis? Is there a different package?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The 'index' object is missing from your code. Without it, the code gives an error.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I've edited the code.

Comment: Here is my read: Since your data variables are all categorical, judging by the description in `?FAMD` it seems that the axes represent the principle components computed after the "categorical variables are transformed into a disjunctive data table (crisp coding) and then scaled using the specific scaling of MCA".  For me means Dim1 is the first principle component, Dim 2 is the second, And the graphs are emphasizing in which component does each individual fall (each row is an individual, represented by the number labels on each dot in the plot).

Comment: @xilliam thank you - I agree with your take on it. The two axes on the graph represent the first two principle components that are selected. But what I don't understand is what these two components mean? What does it say about individuals that are high on axis 1 and low on axis 2 in relation to the survey questions?

Comment: This seems to be more of a stats question than a coding question, so you would probably get a better answer on Cross Validated. That said, Looking at the `fviz_contrib()` calls, isn't it that Dim1 is a principle component based on having high-ish Workload & Backlog, about average Enjoy and low-ish Alone. Dim2 to is having high-ish Alone, about average Enjoy, below average Backlog and lowish Workload. So, high on Dim 1 would mean that that individual's data best mimic Dim 1, Low on Dim 2 that row is an individual whose data is least like Dim 2 ?